# Where can I get the master.dacpac file for SQL Server 2012?

Tags: sql-server-2012, ssdt, visual-studio-2012, system-databases

I am using Visual Studio 2012 Professional with SQL Server Data Tools with a SQL Server 2012 standard edition database instance.
I have been unable to locate a master.dacpac file on either my development machine or on the server hosting the SQL Server instance.

How can I obtain this file, so I can get rid of warnings like the following:

```
SQL71502: Procedure: <ProcedureName> has an unresolved reference to object [sys].[objects]
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should be able to add a Database Reference. Click Project-> Add Database Reference. Click the radio button for System and then master. Code with references to objects in the master db should now build correctly.

Comment: This used to be a major pain in older versions. I was surprised that it is this simple now, but that's all I needed to do. Thanks, Brian!

Comment: Things are definitely going in the right direction with SSDT. Glad it worked for you.

Comment: I copied a solution from one dev computer to another and got this error. Had to remove the database reference and add it again. Worked great.

Answer (score 0):

The master.dacpac and msdb.dacpac files for SQL 2012 are usually installed at `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\SQLDB\Extensions\SqlServer\100\SQLSchemas\`